# PHP hide admin button not working

Tags: php, hide, admin

I run script locally, I want to hide admin button for normal user when both logged (admin or user). My code as below but It's not working, when normal user logged the admin function button still appear.

My Database declaration:

```
<?php
mysql_select_db($database_pods, $pods);
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM `user`";
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $pods) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);

//initialize the session
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}
?>
```

My button code to hide from normal user:

```
<?php if ($row_Recordset1['level'] == 'admin'){
<table align="center" width="50" bordercolor="#000000" border="0">
    <tr>
       <td align="center"><a href="adduser.php">Add User</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
} ?>
```

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient mysql_* functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: What do you get if you var_dump() $row_Recordset1?

Answer (score 0):

In your query

```
SELECT * FROM user
```

you select all users, not only the one who views the page. And in your case the first user in the result set is an admin -- that's why everyone can see this button. You have to query only for the user who views the page, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = $id
```

whereas `id` is a column in the database that uniquely identifies a certain user and `$id` is a PHP variable with the id of the current user. How you get this id depends on the login system you've coded.